# Google app engine: Performance differences between background thread and a task queue

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, task-queue, background-thread, asynchronous

In my GAE app, there are some tasks which were being performed in `taskqueue`s, asynchronously. These tasks involve fetching data from an API and processing it. As the app matured, the data grew in size so the taskqueue limit of 10 minutes started to break in some cases. To fix this I moved the app to GAE `module`s architecture and moved the asynchronous execution to a `backgrouindThread`. This works but the execution has become a lot slower, typically taking 8x time. What is the reason behind this? What is the solution/workaround for this, if any?

EDIT:

I suppose it's because of poor multithreaded performance of python. Is it true? Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: What do you see in the logs? Is it possible that startup time explains the difference?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin As far as I have seen, it's the actual execution what takes time and not any delay in starting the thread.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin, Yes, the highest configuration to be specific. One difference though, the later added module has basic scaling. Just curious, does the number of instances change anything regarding a single execution here? I think it won't but just being sure....

Comment: Only a startup time, but you say it's not the cause.

Comment: If you set a low max_instances it can bottle neck execution. If you send 10 requests, but max at 5 instances it will take 2ce as long to run all the tasks.

Comment: @Bruyere: Yep I understand that, thanks. But this performance degrade is observed per request :-/ .